# How to replace Jinja2 expressions inside expressions?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm using Ansible templates and I'm importing variables from an external file `app_vars.yml`:

```
# App list
apps:
- app1

# App1 vars
app1:
  environments:
  - demo
  - test
  filebeat_properties:
    paths:
    - /home/_env_-app/logs/_env_-*.log
    fields:
      app_id: _env_
```

In the template `filebeat_template.yml` I'm currently just replacing the `_env_` string with `env` from the `for` loop using the `replace()` filter like this:

```
{% for app in apps %}
  {% for env in vars[app]["environments"] %}
- type: log
  enabled: true
  {{ vars[app]["filebeat_properties"] | to_nice_yaml(indent=2, width=9999) | indent(2) | replace("_env_", env) }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I was wondering is there some syntax that lets me mark the Jinja expression-to-be-replaced in the `app_vars.yml` file? Kind of like this

```
...
paths:
- /home/{{ env }}-app/logs/_env_-*.log
fields:
  app_id: {{ env }}
```

where `{{ env }}` is to be replaced in the template file with the `for` loop `env` variable? Adding `""` around it makes it just a string.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using `{{ env }}` directly in your var file ?

I'm doing this kind of this myself, for example

```yaml
grafana_security:
  admin_user: "{{ metadata_owner }}-{{ metadata_environment }}-admin"
```

Try it, with facts variables it should work. But later on, be careful about the [variables precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). For the above example I'm defining my `metadata_*` in `group_var/somegroup.yml`, the above snippet is in another `group_var/monitoring.yml`, and this way it works. I tried other combinations which didn't, like using a value from a role's default/main.yml in group_vars/something.yml.